# how can I simplify this $\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{2i}+\sqrt{3i}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Is there an easy way to simplify  the
$$\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{2i}+\sqrt{3i}$$

Comment: what's your definition of $\sqrt{i}$? But either way, $\sqrt{i} +  \sqrt{2i} +  \sqrt{3i} = (1+ \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}) \sqrt{i}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: write $i=e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$ and everything should follow.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following
$$i=\frac{1}{2}(1+i)^2$$
so
$$\sqrt{i}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(1+i)^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1+i)$$
$$\sqrt{2i}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{2}(1+i)^2}=(1+i)$$
$$\sqrt{3i}=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}(1+i)^2}=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}(1+i)$$

Comment: In complex numbers, we do not have $\sqrt{z^2} = |z|$.

Comment: @Essam consider $\sqrt{(i)^2}$

Comment: @GEdgar thank you for your comment